# Propagate onHover to child views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two independent views (e.g. simple Checkbox and Card). Both have own `onHover` listener. I need somehow propagate hover event from parent to child (e.g. when Card has Checkbox inside. Now it only works if I hover directly on the Checkbox).

```
struct Checkbox: View {
    @State private var isHovered = false

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .background(isHovered ? .red : .blue)
            .onHover { isHovered in
                self.isHovered = isHovered
            }
    }
}

struct Card: View {
    @State private var isHovered = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Label")
            Checkbox()
        }
        .onHover(perform: { isHovered in
            self.isHovered = isHovered
        })
        .background(isHovered ? .red : .blue)
    }
}
```

I don't want to use a Binding, because if I used Checkbox as a standalone, it will always expect a Binding that it doesn't need.

Comment: Read about `Binding`s. Store the child's hover state at the parent level. Or, if you want to decouple them, use a PreferenceKey to transmit the child status up the chain to the parent.

Comment: I don't like Binding, because if I used Checkbox as standalone, it will always expect some Binding that it doesn't need.

Comment: It's either a single state ie. coordinated .onHover (as referred to by passing a binding) or independent and the concept of hover is different logic in both views. That is the simplest way to proceed although you can create your own view initialiser that accepts an Optional Binding that will let the view sync the binding if one is provided or run its own logic if not. A little more complicated though.

Comment: @JaSHin Okay, use a `PreferenceKey` then

Comment: PreferenceKey is quite a rabbit hole although sure it can be down. See alternative. Best to keep separate views and manage the bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with your comments. By passing the binding rather than having a state in both views you can get full information for how you want your view to respond. A simple form has each view managing their own @State for the hover or sharing a binding for a single state. As mentioned previously you can pass "optional" bindings to have the views either share the hover state or manage each separately and the code below shows that.

This provides an optional binding to the child (Checkbox) view (ie if it should react to parent onHover state it can, if not pass nil dependency). There are a few other things in your code that you need to be aware of eg. you were setting circle background (which is actually setting the background of the containing frame rectangle) rather than the fill for the actual circle.

```
    struct Checkbox: View {
    @State var internalHover: Bool = false
    var isHovered: Binding<Bool>? = nil
    @State var localIsHover: Bool = false
    var whatIsHovered: Bool {
        if let isHovered {
            return isHovered.wrappedValue
        } else {
            return localIsHover
        }
    }
    
    init(_ isHovered: Binding<Bool>? = nil) {
        self.isHovered = isHovered
    }

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(whatIsHovered ? .green : .cyan)
            .onHover { hover in
            if self.isHovered != nil {
                   self.isHovered?.wrappedValue = hover
               }
               localIsHover = hover
           }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isHovered = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Label")
            Checkbox( $isHovered ) // With a binding
            Checkbox() // with no binding
        }
        .background(isHovered ? .red : .blue)
        .onHover(perform: { isHovered in
            self.isHovered = isHovered
        })
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't like Binding, because if I used Checkbox as standalone, it will always expect some Binding that it doesn't need.

Comment: Have updated the answer to include code that allows you to pass optional binding to the child view. I think this is what you need.

Comment: Yes. I did same thing, but I hoped that exist better solution.